# How can I get my galaxy 4 watch to show on google maps?

Tags: location-services, smartwatch, samsung-galaxy-watch-active

I have a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 40mm watch with LTE for my son.  I had to use an old galaxy phone to set it up, since I wanted it to be associated with his accounts completely separate from mine (basically samsung and google accounts).  But after that, it seems to be self-sufficient for the most part, i.e. we can text and call without the phone even being on.

I don't want to rely on the phone at all for this watch, unless we need to reset it or change a specific configuration.  I want my son to be able to effectively use it for calls, texts, and GPS location.  It's this last part that I can't figure out.  He has a google account and its configured on the watch and the Location Services are on, but I cannot see his watch from any apps.  Google Maps doesn't show his location, despite location sharing being on + configured to share with me too.  Thus, I don't know how to find the watch's location aside from using the phone that it is paired with, which like I said, I don't want to rely on.

Are there some apps or other configurations that can allow me to see where this watch's locations at all times?